# Create a blockquote in first paragraph of a footnote

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to create a footnote that has a blockquote for the footnote. Like this:

```
This is a footnoted item[^1].

[^1]: > Foot note with a blockquote.

    > Another blockquote.
```

But the result is this:

```
This is a footnoted item1.

1. > Footnote with a blockquote.

       Another blockquote.
```

So the first paragraph doesn't default to the blockquote. Is it possible to blockquote the first paragraph?

Comment: Did you mean `[^1]` instead of `^[1]`?  When I try it with `[^1]` I get a blockquote in a note.

Comment: @JohnMacFarlane Good catch. I'll fix that. That wasn't my problem though. It was because I was putting a space after the colon.

Answer (score 0):

No space should be left between the colon and the greater than symbol. So not `: > F` but `:> F`. That seemed to fix the problem.

```
This is a footnoted item[^1].

[^1]:> Foot note with a blockquote.

    > Another blockquote.
```

Comment: It works fine with a space before `>`, at least in the most recent release.

Comment: hhmm. I'll have to look at it again. I thought that that was all I changed and it started working. I must have changed something else also.